# Paperclip Video Skewed (does not maintain aspect ratio)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, video-streaming, paperclip, transcoding

The video uploaded does not maintain aspect ratio. In the readme (paperclip av-transcoder) it says, " '!' - Keep the same aspect of the image/video, but with the passed dimension." I have also tried the other options(<>#!) and none of them effect the size of the video.

My goal is to be able to be able to have the video returned in a square (while maintaining the aspect ratio). Cropping from the center would be ideal, as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I included my code below.

```
class Video < Post

  Paperclip.interpolates :id do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.id
  end

  #basename/extension is paperclip interpolation from attachment, can write own interpolations as needed

  # have to link /usr/local/bin to the linuxbrew version of ffmpeg
  has_attached_file :video,  path: "/posts/videos/:id/:style.:extension",
  :styles => {
    :square => {:geometry => "500x500!", :format => 'mp4', :streaming => true }
  },
  :processors => [:transcoder]

  validates_attachment :video, :presence => true,
                           :content_type => { content_type: ["video/mp4", "video/mov", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4", "video/quicktime"] }

  def video_url
    video = self.video
    if video.present?
      return video.url(:square)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an open issue, the gem does not forward parameters to `av`

https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder/issues/31

you can use the old deprecated ffmpeg transcoder [paperclip-ffmpeg](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg/tree/stable),

it's ugly but it's the only thing that works for now, I asked if there's a workaround https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder/issues/32, so we'll see...